# Spring MVC Redirecting not working when long data is passed

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC and Spring Security.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/GetListDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getListDetails(HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal) {
    logger.debug("Processing fetching of List Details.");

    ModelAndView mnv = new ModelAndView("redirect:CampaignManager");
    mnv.addObject("request","list");
    mnv.addObject("listTemplateMsisdnJson","//here my json data length is around 23973 characters long.");
    logger.debug("Completed Processing of fetching of List Details, returning.");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/CampaignManager", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getHomePage(HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal) {
    logger.debug("Processing CM");
}
```

Now, when request comes like "/GetListDetails", control comes to proper function and prints,
"Processing fetching of List Details." but after that No data comes in browser and in chrome it prints "No data received".
Also, control doesn't prints "Processing CM" line.

In logs, it shows like this.

```
[2014-01-27 20:53:17,556]DEBUG 21274[http-8080-3] - com.on.smsconnect.controller.ListTemplateController.getListDetails(ListTemplateController.java:609) - Completed Processing of fetching of List Details, returning.
[2014-01-27 20:53:17,558]DEBUG 21276[http-8080-3] - org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531) - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'redirect:CampaignManager'
[2014-01-27 20:53:17,559]DEBUG 21277[http-8080-3] - org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1206) - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView: name 'redirect:CampaignManager'; URL [CampaignManager]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
[2014-01-27 20:53:17,593]DEBUG 21311[http-8080-3] - org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) - Successfully completed request
[2014-01-27 20:53:17,594]DEBUG 21312[http-8080-3] - org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) - Chain processed normally
[2014-01-27 20:53:17,594]DEBUG 21312[http-8080-3] - org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:97) - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
[2014-01-27 20:53:17,598]DEBUG 21316[http-8080-5] - org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116) - Checking match of request : '/getlistdetails'; against 'gateway/resources/**'
[2014-01-27 20:53:17,599]DEBUG 21317[http-8080-5] - org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116) - Checking match of request : '/getlistdetails'; against '/resources/**'
[2014-01-27 20:53:17,599]DEBUG 21317[http-8080-5] - org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116) - Checking match of request : '/getlistdetails'; against '/jsp/resources/**'
[2014-01-27 20:53:17,599]DEBUG 21317[http-8080-5] - org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116) - Checking match of request : '/getlistdetails'; against '/jsp/img**'
```

Now when my json data is less, then everything works fine.

Edited:

Correct flow display like this.

```
[2014-01-27 17:23:20,123]DEBUG 46997[http-8080-6] - org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1206) - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView: name 'redirect:CampaignManager'; URL [CampaignManager]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
[2014-01-27 17:23:20,124]DEBUG 46998[http-8080-6] - org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) - Successfully completed request
[2014-01-27 17:23:20,124]DEBUG 46998[http-8080-6] - org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) - Chain processed normally
[2014-01-27 17:23:20,124]DEBUG 46998[http-8080-6] - org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:97) - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
[2014-01-27 17:23:20,130]DEBUG 47004[http-8080-6] - org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116) - Checking match of request : '/campaignmanager'; against 'gateway/resources/**'
[2014-01-27 17:23:20,131]DEBUG 47005[http-8080-6] - org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116) - Checking match of request : '/campaignmanager'; against '/resources/**'
[2014-01-27 17:23:20,131]DEBUG 47005[http-8080-6] - org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116) - Checking match of request : '/campaignmanager'; against '/jsp/resources/**'
[2014-01-27 17:23:20,131]DEBUG 47005[http-8080-6] - org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116) - Checking match of request : '/campaignmanager'; against '/jsp/img**'
```

Comment: What do the logs look like when it works the way you expect?

Comment: I don't see any difference.

Comment: Why do you do a redirect with so much data and even after a GET request? I know the *post-redirect-get* pattern but nog the *get-redirect-get* pattern. Is there any good reason you do a redirect instead of simply rendering the view directly?

Comment: Because in my dashboard I am displaying many things and when user click on list section along with other details list details should also get displayed. so what I am doing is I have centralized location where default data is fetched from DB and displayed and respective click data I made separate function which after filling passed data to Centralized section which fetch common details and send everything to Dashboard... am I wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you do a redirect with a lot of attributes encoded in the URL differs per browser. In general it is a bad idea to put too much into the URL.

It is probably better to put the large objects in a `RedirectAttributes` instead of encoding it in the url. You can simply add it as an argument to your method and put the data in there, it will be available in the model after the redirect.

Comment: I am not aware of RedirectAttributes, let me go through or if you can help me with some links.